# Brightness - external monitor drivers

Tags: arch-linux, multi-monitor, xrandr, plasma, backlight

I'm using Linux arch on Thinkpad X1C6.
I bought external monitor Samsung C27F396FHU and I have a problem with brightness.

I cannot use a physical button to adjust the brightness of the monitor - at first,  on the "quick acces" there was a text "unavailable", and in the main menu, the brightness text it was non-existant. After installing drivers:
`sudo pacman -S xf86-video-intel`

The "brightness" row appeared on the monitor main menu, but the text is dimmed (unclickable).

`xrandr --output HDMI-1 --brightness 0.1` dims the screen artificially (rgb-like), but doesn't affect the backlight (true brightness).

`sudo modprobe i2c-dev; sudo ddcutil capabilities` state that `MCCS version: not present`.

I also tried xorg-xbacklight, but writing `xbacklight -set 25` changes just the brightness of a laptop, not monitor. (I don't know what to type as the display of `xbacklight -display <display>`.)

TL;DR;
Brightness doesn't work on an external monitor on my ArchLinux, and I have no clue what can I do to fix it.

`sudo ddcutil detect`

```
Display 1
   I2C bus:             /dev/i2c-3
   EDID synopsis:
      Mfg id:           SAM
      Model:            C27F390
      Serial number:    H4ZM504450
      Manufacture year: 2019
      EDID version:     1.3
   VCP version:         2.0
```

Answer (score 1):

As it came out, this monitor had "eye saving" mode that disabled brightness internally so manipulating it wasn't possible programmatically. I had to turn off the eye saving mode in OSD, and then everything worked like charm.

ddcutil enabled everything else:

1. `sudo ddcutil vcpinfo` to get the list of feature codes regarding your monitor
2. `sudo ddcutil getvcp 0x10` in my case to know the value of the feature I want to change
3. `sudo ddcutil setvcp 0x10 42` to set the brightness feature to 42.